# Let's advertise Writing on other sites (2018 edition)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It's a new year and [we have a new name](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/1993).  Let's make (or update) ads to promote Writing Stack Exchange on other sites on the network!

Last year we [made several new ads](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1233/1993).  For some, maybe we just need to change the site name and repost.  For others, we might want to change the content, taking into account feedback we've received.  Please visit [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) if you want to discuss and brainstorm.  Please post ads here!

This post is not for ads to run on *our* site; as a beta site we don't get ads.  This post is to collect ads to submit on *other* (non-beta) sites like Software Engineering, Worldbuilding, and Academia.  (Got more ideas?  Please share!)

---

Ads posted on other sites:

- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5806/28) (has reached voting threshold)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8694/124448) (has reached voting threshold)
- [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3988/87401)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4123/58892) (has reached voting threshold)
- [Aviation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3485/29027)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11743/32756)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11235/8816)
- [Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7786/19667)
- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4485/137939)
- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28001/529170)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8668/33153) (has reached voting threshold)

Other possibilities that have been suggested:

- TeX and LaTeX (focus on technical, academic, and scientific writing)
- User Experience
- The Workplace
- Graphic Design
- Other technical sites? (which?)

Answer (score 14):

This would replace the Worldbuilding ad from last year. Monica has asked that I go ahead and post it over there, so will. I like the background image on this one much better :o)

[image]

I've darkened the font up some, which makes it stand out a little more. Looking for feedback if I could, please.

[image]

Comment: Post on Worldbuilding: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5806/28

Comment: The bottom part of the text is a little hard to distinguish against the background color.

Comment: @ChristianRau - I'll see if I can tweak it a little ... wash out that part of the image a little. PhotoShop is a wonderful tool :o)

Comment: What if the text is closer to the green of the quill to make it more readable?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Possibly. I'll look at it this evening or tomorrow. One of the issues we could run into would be the aesthetics issue, where it just doesn't work. I appreciate the input and will take a look. I also might take a look at changing the slight border which goes around the lettering. Right now it is very dark. If I lighten it up some, it should help the letters stand out a little better.

Comment: @ChristianRau - I've put a new image above. See if this works better for you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Certainly better than before indeed.

Comment: @ChristianRau - It pops a lot better at the 300x250 display size as well. I'll wait for Monica's feedback, but it will probably replace the one which is over on WB when I get the okay from her.

Comment: The darker version is a win. :-)

Comment: Yes, I definitely like the darker version better as well.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Comment: This ad was designed for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8694/124448), and maybe works on some other technical sites too -- feel free to suggest some.

Comment: Would SuperUser work?

Answer (score 6):

[image: Just. Write.]

Comment: Not sure if this meets the requirements. It is meant to be a click-bait for coding sites.

Comment: Thanks.  Does anybody have suggestions for code-oriented sites to submit this to?  I think SO's ads are different (and I also suspect they wouldn't welcome an ad from us), but they're not the only technical site on the network. :-)  (Sites need to be out of beta to get ads.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio How about *Code Review*? By the way: are there plans to put ads on language related sites such as *English Language & Usage* or *Japanese Language* (I am not active on either site)?

Comment: @Secespitus "plans" ascribes way too much organization. :-)  Consider this a community-run project; we welcome ideas from everybody!  In the past we advertised the weekly writing chats (when we had them) on EL&U, so I think they'd be receptive to an ad from us -- do you have ideas on what it should say?  (Can you make it?)

Comment: @Secespitus actually, for Code Review maybe we want an ad that's more along the lines of "Reviewers can't understand your code? Bring your questions about documentation to Writing!".  Just a thought.

Comment: @MonicaCellio A first idea: "Want to put your skills to the test in a project? / Blog / Book / Short Story / Script / ... / Learn how to do it - on Writing.SE!" I am not an ad designer, so I'll leave that to someone who knows what they are doing. Going for the documentation on *Code Review* sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @Secespitus  I can try to produce something along those lines. Just give me 24h :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's my attempt at a community ad for Academia.SE (and possibly other science-oriented sites):

[image: Suggestion for community ad]

Second version: Made the book a bit lighter, and added a small white border to the font

[image: Second version]

I've found out how to add the extra border without making the font thinner; therefore a third version:

[image: Third version]

Comment: Nice!  Thank you.  I like how you've drawn from a variety of disciplines so we can run this on science sites as well as Academia.  I am the wrong person to judge color/contrast stuff (because I have some funky vision stuff), so question: is the text that goes over the purple book sufficiently visible, especially at 300x250?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I've now added a second version.

Comment: That looks good to me -- thanks so much!

Comment: I submitted this to Academia and Chemistry (links in the question).  I picked Chemistry among the science sites because they have several ads on their site already (i.e. they use the feature) and they advertise their site on other sites.  We can try other science sites too, but I didn't want to blast it out to everybody at once when I'm not a user on most of the sites already.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Do you think it would also be appropriate for Mathematics.SE?

Comment: It looks like they've downvoted all the ads for other SE sites, but I see you have a lot of rep there, so do you want to go ahead and post it there?  Let me know when you do so I can add a link to the list in the question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I looked over the downvoted ads. Two of them are to sites totally non-related to mathematics (and both of those are not even working correctly, which probably got them some of the downvotes), one is an area51 proposal, and the remaining one had only one downvote (I now upvoted that one). So I went ahead and posted the ad; let's see how it fares.

Comment: Academia pointed out that because this ad has a white background, it requires a 2px border.  Could you adjust that please?  I posted [this version](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3988/87401) there.  Thanks!  (Also affects Chemistry, where we've reached the score threshold.)

Answer (score 5):

**Fiction Variant**

[image]

**Tech Writing Variant**

[image]

This would work nicely on aviation or engineering.

**Blank**

[image]

Add your meme here.

Comment: Engineering is still in beta so can't do ads, but Aviation is possible!  (Or did you mean Electrical Engineering, which isn't beta?  I hadn't noticed that there were both EE and Eng.)

Comment: I'm just thinking laterally. Obviously Leonardo's Helicopter is a mechanical engineering/aviation project, but I think the tech-writer tag line works for **any** engineering discipline which needs documentation. I also think that the imagery is less appropriate for software than **proper** engineering disciplines.

Comment: Agreed -- tech writing is not just software.  In fact, with the integration of the Tech Comm community we've added a software-documentation tag.

Answer (score 5):

A word press plug-in:

[image] [image]

Designed for `wordpress` development and `webmasters`

Comment: I posted on Wordpress Development.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone loves pictures of cats on the internet.

[image]

Either `webmasters` or `graphicdesign`.

Comment: The original [Grumpy Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumpy_Cat) is intellectual property. [Sad-Annoyed Cat](https://www.flickr.com/photos/39969232@N08/16760847493/in/photolist-rx6J2c-o7Zz8L-aacX4c-4rJKfm-6igiAw-6MQKBt-dYye4K-6ysJLU-4Gp4s6-mEk81w-9wM8bC-a1tbSE-iAKa5n-qtBbR-kCDgpu-oQDGFU-pEcuwd-8Axp3h-6wevSL-6cTGqP-nKTpct-peCVgC-fxb44t-8KMoL3-2YKWfU-5KcTis-73vAmP-a6tEAi-8SqXfL-aGzLXx-cBpFNf-yPSMU-8GxFd6-4uzdRc-5cTP3S-nqxkE-7Gbc9T-5styge-gcHfGd-khZDAc-k6U32-zx8J3-7UTWcC-dTsX1Y-FuiPJ4-gvNiuD-qoyst6-amsM1h-Rp4WR-ip39jm) is public domain.

Answer (score 3):

This one should be self explanatory:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One more with a dictionary motif for English Language.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Similarly using a citation motif could work for Academia.

I've copied the tag line from [celtschk](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1472/29582)'s excellent post - I'm not lobbying for the use of this right now, just uploading a proposal for the basic idea to be used as a re-skin of the current ad concept when required.

[image]

The biggest issue is that *Prof. S.E. Writing* is obviously working in *Humanities* - so it wouldn't work on Chemistry for example.

The other problem is that the "citation" text appears much smaller than the "dictionary" text as it is attempting to invoke single column text rather than a two-column layout.

**Blank**

[image]

Add your meme here.

Comment: A [comment on the EL&U ad post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11167/community-promotion-ads-2018/11235?noredirect=1#comment47493_11235) thought the pen was something crossed out.  Could you do something to clarify that?  Thanks.  (Probably applies to the RPG add too.)

Comment: It is potentially the Black and Blue Dress issue as Dan Bron stated. There is no context for the brain to infer the correct lighting conditions and as the image size is reduced the pixellation will be increased and the likelyhood for confusion increased. I've always seen it as a pen of course.  RPG is probably OK since the pen is larger and hence provides more context. I'd be interested to find out if anyone else has an issue with it.

Comment: Potential solutions: a) *delete the pen* - removing the visual element will leave the ad as text only and rather dull. b) *increase the size of the pen* - this will affect the overall balance c) *angle the pen* - may work - same information different context  d) *find another pen* - could affect the color scheme and the existing pen is nicely expensive.

Comment: I went with a mix of b) and c). - tell me what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Something from the Bulwer-Lytton Ad Agency:

[image]

I think it would work for RPG

**Tech Writing Variant**

[image]

Anything Software Related

**Blank**

[image]

Add your meme here.

Answer (score 2):

Just a word cloud of the major site tags

[image]

**Blank**

[image]

Add your meme here.

Comment: Science Fiction & Fantasy, maybe?

Comment: Well the word cloud does include both halves of their site title, and the black background would fit nicely with their color scheme.